# Is it possible to deploy cordova to webserver？

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am a new Cordova developer. I want deploy my cordova platform (android/ios) source to webserver (ex:tomcat), 
my step:

1. put all of android/assets file to webserver/webapp dir
2. open my android project , mofify loadUrl to http://XX.XX.XX/android/assets
3. The html res is loaded well, but my plugin is not work, It seem the plugin is not loaded

My questions is how can I deploy the source on the remote webserver, and my plugin will work well。

Comment: No way, that does not work. On the other hand, if this would work, your app would be rejected in the stores.

Comment: Only for technical implementation is it can be implemented ? Why?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying cordova application there are two parts come into picture.

1) All the HTML which is there in asset folder will get compiled to APK, including your plugin and other plugin which you may have used.

2) Other part is web service or server side scripting to deal with data manipulation in DB using app.

- so compiled application will go into device
- and service side script will go to web server

Hope, i have given answer to your question.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But my purpose is deploy Html , css, js to my webserver and I can update content from remote host, not compiled in APK. If I deploy to webserver, I found all plugin is not work.

Comment: plugin will not work because it resides outside the asset folder, and if you want it to work you need to install everything on server which you install locally to do development, did you get my point?

Comment: Yes, I got it. but I don't know how to do it , Can you give me a sample?

Comment: no example needed here, what i am saying is configure and upload all the things on server which you did in local for starting development, and that is it.

Comment: OK, Thanks, I will try!